# Pass multiple LinkedList's from one class to another - Java

Tags: java, linked-list

I have 2 LinkedLists and I want to pass them through an Object to another class. I tried this code but I get error: **java.lang.ClassCastException: [D cannot be cast to java.util.LinkedList**.

**First class:**

```
public class class1{
public Object[] method1(LinkedList<Point> xList,LinkedList<Point> yList){

xList.add(new Point(10,10));
yList.add(new Point(20,10));

return new Object[]{xList, yList};
}
}
```

**Second Class**:

```
public class class2{
public void method2(){

LinkedList<Point> xPoints = new LinkedList<Point>();
LinkedList<Point> yPoints = new LinkedList<Point>();

xPoints.add(new Point(20,40));
yPoints.add(new Point(15,15));

class1 get = new class1();
Object getObj[] = get.method1(xPoints,yPoints);

xPoints = (LinkedList<Point>) getObj[0];
yPoints = (LinkedList<Point>) getObj[1];
}
```

Also, eclipse suggested to write this "@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")" outside of method1 and method2.

Comment: Which line are you getting the error in?

Comment: xPoints = (LinkedList<Point>) getObj[0];

Comment: what's your point @BN0LD?

Comment: There is no casting issue . What are you trying to do in places like `yPoints.add(15,15)`? Post full stacktrace  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently your code does not compile correctly, because you cannot write

```
xPoints.add(20,40);
```

You should use

```
xPoints.add(new Point(20,40));
```

After fixing this in four places it compiles and runs correctly, no ClassCastException is reported.

Please note that as your `method1` modifies the list which was supplied by parameter, you should not return it at all. Just use:

```
public void method1(LinkedList<Point> xList, LinkedList<Point> yList) {
    xList.add(new Point(10, 10));
    yList.add(new Point(20, 10));
}

public void method2() {

    LinkedList<Point> xPoints = new LinkedList<Point>();
    LinkedList<Point> yPoints = new LinkedList<Point>();

    xPoints.add(new Point(20, 40));
    yPoints.add(new Point(15, 15));

    class1 get = new class1();
    get.method1(xPoints, yPoints);
    // use xPoints and yPoints here: new point is already added
}
```

Comment: This is not what I want. I want to pass the updated version of the LinkedList back to the method2. When I try: xPoints = (LinkedList<Point>) getObj[0];   I get error.

Comment: @Steve, to use the updated version in method2 you don't have to return it. It's updated in-place. Just try. For example, use `System.out.println(xPoints)` in `method2` after calling the `method1` and you will see that `xPoints` already contains two points.